# How can i select the fields that i want retrieve using Autopopulate Mongoose Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using the plugin mongoose-autopopulate but i don't know how to specify the fields that i want retrieve from the populated collection.

Here is my schema...

```
const categoriaSchema = new Schema({
    data: { type: String },
    label: { type: String },
    children: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categorias',
        autopopulate: true
    }],
    father: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categorias',
        autopopulate: true
    },
    eventos: { type: Boolean },
    tienda: { type: Boolean },
    productos: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'productos',
        autopopulate: true
    }]
})
```

So i would like to select the fields at children populated collection, because the productos fields bring a lot of documents.

How can i have an output like this...

```
{
    data: "Electronic",
    label: "Electronic",
    children: [
        { 
        data: "Mobiles",
        label: "Mobiles",
        children: [
            {   
            data: "Samsung",
            label: "Samsung",
            children: [],
            eventos: true;
            tienda: true;
            }
        ],
        eventos: true;
        tienda: true;
        }
    ],
    eventos: true;
    tienda: true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.

```
  children: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categorias',
        autopopulate: { select: '-productos' },

    }],
```

autopopulate accepts options then you can select or unselect the fields that you want exclude or add.